# Change the font color in a field using lotus script or @command

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

Is there a way to change the font color and its background of a rich text field? The goal here is to get a type of color whenever a word is changed from a list.

For instance, I can have a table with two columns, where first column is related to a type of vehicle and the second it is related to type of combustible used. So, let's imagine that every time a vehicle uses gasoline, so its wording should be shown yellow text and the field background in black. On the other hand, if a vehicle uses electrical, its wording should be shown red and the field background in green...

I know that there is a command but I do not know how to use it for more than one value.

```
@Command([TextSetFontColor]; [Red])
```

Any help?

Comment: formatted text and cleaned up some grammar

Comment: Thanks Greg, I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the font and color of the existing text in a rich text field with the Notes @formulas or @commands. There are some tricks you can do (e.g., multiple subforms containing the same field, with different backgrounds and fonts, and a computed subform formula, or maybe with multiple computed-for-display fields and hide-whens - but the text would not be editable that way) before the text is entered into the field. If you want to change the font of already-existing rich text, you'll probably need to use the Notes C or C++ APIs, the MIDAS Rich Text API from Genii software. I think the background will have to be done with computed subforms or hide-whens and computed-for-display fields (for non-editable rich text), no matter what.

Comment: Thanks Richard, what about changing only the font text color ?

Comment: As I said, either the Notes C or C++ API, or the MIDAS Rich Text API from Genii Software. I don't believe you can do it with LotusScript or formulas.